# makeNthChildOf() method is missing on etrepat/baum laravel package

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jstree

I am using [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) laravel package along with [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) jQuery plugin to manage categories.

In jstree there is a **[move_node.jstree](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=move&f=move_node.jstree)** method used to move nodes. it has useful properties to get info about move action like `parent` , `old
_parent`, ... and a `position` that returns new position of moved child node in parent node.

In the other hand there is methods to move nodes too.([here](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#moving-nodes-around)). but there is not any method like `makeNthChildOf()` that can use to place a child node at specific position of a parent node. like:

```
$node->makeNthChildOf(newPosition , $parent)
```

Now in the client to move nodes I wrote this:

```
 $treeview.on('move_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            $.post('/move', {
                'CategoryID': data.node.id,
                'newParent': data.parent,
                'oldParent': data.old_parent
            }, function (res) {
                data.instance.open_node(data.parent);
            }, 'json');
        });
```

And in the laravel :

```
public function move (Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only('newParent', 'oldParent', 'CategoryID');

        $currentNode = Category::find($data['CategoryID']);
        if ($data['newParent'] == '#') {
            $currentNode->makeRoot();
        } else {
            $currentNode->makeChildOf($data['newParent']);
        }

        return ['success' => true];
    }
```

But above code can not do that I want and just can to move a node from a parent to another parent.

I want to know is there any alternate approach to doing that functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe I found a way to accomplish this.  I just threw it together quickly, so sorry for the ugly code:

First, I use ajax, so I build up the form data with the node information

```
formData = "node_id=" + data.node.id + "&name=" + data.node.text + "&_token=" + $("input[name=_token]").val() + "&parent=" + data.parent + "&position=" + data.position + "&old_position=" + data.old_position + "&old_parent=" + data.old_parent;
```

Next, we create a quick helper function to determine what position our current node is in.  It will just loop through all the decendants of the parent node and literally count them.

```
private function findPosition($decendants, $position) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($decendants as $decendant) {
        if ($i == $position) {
            return $decendant;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

And then we can move the node to it's correct spot:

```
//We first need to account for moving within same node, but below it's current position.  Without this the node will be moved 1 position off.
    if ($parent == $old_parent) {
        if ($position > $old_position) {
            $position = $position +1;
        }
    }

    $parent = BaumTest::find($parent);
    $decendants = $parent->getImmediateDescendants();
    $moveTo = $this->findPosition($decendants, $position);
    $node = BaumTest::find($node_id);

//If the parent we are moving to doesn't have any decendents,  just move it now
    if ($parent->isLeaf()) {
        $node->makeChildOf($parent);
        return array("error"=>false, "successMessage"=>"Sucessfully Moved!");
    }

  //This takes care of it we are moving it into the last position
    if (is_null($moveTo)) {
        $node->makeLastChildOf($parent);
        return array("error"=>false, "successMessage"=>"Sucessfully Moved!");
    }

 $node->moveToLeftOf($moveTo);
```